# javaFX 2.0 how to select files aka FileChooser

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm trying out the new JavaFx 2.0 beta release but cannot find anyway of selecting files using a dialog box like JfileChooser.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is now available in beta 36 http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html

Answer (score 4):

At present there aren't any file chooser dialogs available in JavaFX 2.0 beta. Your best option in the short-term is to use a TreeView and browse your file system with that. Creating a TreeView file system browser is rather simple.

Comment: Wow, Jonathan, That was very quick. Anyway thanks for the response. I thought I was missing something. I can hard code the path for now but is a file chooser in the works or I have to start ripping the JFilechooser in swing apart?

Comment: What I was actually going to do was to build the directory structure for a folder and show it in a treeview. I already have the treview in my UI so maybe a composite component that does that will help a lot since I think a lot of people will be trying to represent folder structures. Tx

Comment: Farouk, I can't really comment a great deal about what is coming up. Of course, a UI toolkit wouldn't be very useful without dialogs, but whether they end up in JavaFX 2.0 hasn't been announced.

Comment: how is it possible to user from TreeView for browsing files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use form filechoser - as you know swing components can used in javafx 2.0.

```
 b.setLayoutY(50);
b.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.showDialog(javafxPanel, null);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

mehdi is correct that you can use JFileChooser in your FX 2.0 app. I am doing it also. However, it's not correct to say that you can use swing components inside of JavaFX 2.0: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-12100

Also, I am experiencing issues where the JFileChooser dialog window does not reliably appear on top of the main application window.

http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-13839 covers adding a file chooser dialog to the FX 2.0 toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Just note, that there are no standard dialogs (information, warning, error) in JavaFX2. BTW, why? Using [JavaFxDialog project](https://github.com/4ntoine/JavaFxDialog) for now.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaFX **2.1** you can use an object of class [javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html).